# Trouble using the `threading` module -- AttributeError: module 'threading' has no attribute 'RLock'

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I get the following errors:

```
AttributeError: module 'threading' has no attribute 'RLock'
Exception ignored in: <module 'threading' from 'D:\\PYTHON_STACKOVERFLOW_ANSWERS\\threading.py'>
AttributeError: module 'threading' has no attribute '_shutdown'
```

My code is shown below:

```
import logging
import threading
import time

def thread_function(name):
    logging.info("Thread %s: starting", name)
    time.sleep(2)
    logging.info("Thread %s: finishing", name)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    format = "%(asctime)s: %(message)s"
    logging.basicConfig(
        format=format,
        level=logging.INFO,
        datefmt="%H:%M:%S"
    )
    logging.info("Main    : before creating thread")
    x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(1,))
    logging.info("Main    : before running thread")
    x.start()
    logging.info("Main    : wait for the thread to finish")
    # x.join()
    logging.info("Main    : all done")
```

Stack overflow complains, "It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details." So I'm going to put this little bit of text at the end here; sorry.

Answer (score 9):

If you get this error, it means you likely named one of your own files `threading.py` As such, the import imports your own file instead of importing the expected library.

Although it's a silly mistake, hopefully someone googling, "`AttributeError: module 'threading' has no attribute 'RLock'`" will find this answer helpful.